# Htop shows a mysqld that isn't in filesystem?

Tags: mysql, systemd, htop

Upon cleaning up my filesystem and uninstalling services I don't use, I noticed that 'htop' shows what appears to be a MySQL daemon running at

/usr/sbin/mysqld

The thing is I don't have any MySQL installed manually, and I purposely removed MySQL / Maria installations. When I look at the location:

/usr/sbin/mysqld

It doesn't even exist on the filesystem. Systemctl status queries return nothing for 'mysql' or 'mysqld'.

Any thoughts? Is this a sign of some malicious activity, or some strangeness in htop cache? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This is an old Ubuntu 20.04 install and as per Matigo's suggestion I checked docker. There was a docker install which I purged but this /usr/sbin/mysqld persists after a reboot. I will look into other programs which may be creating / using filesystems or pseudo-file systems.

Comment: Are you running any Docker containers that might use MySQL?

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, it could be, I will check and respond, will edit this comment.